# Is it possible to use the input() function to have the user input a variable for an object?

Tags: python, class, object, input

Let's say I have a class and an object of said class:

```
class Rock:
    def __init__(self, name, group):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group

granite = Rock('Granite', 'Igneous')
```

Now let's say I want the user to input a rock, so I have a line such as this:

```
rock = input('Type the name of a rock: ')
```

Based on what rock the user inputs, I want it to print out a string such as, "Granite belongs to the igneous group." I can achieve this string by typing:

```
print(granite.name + ' belongs to the ' + granite.group + ' group.')
```

However, this only gives the illusion of choice, as if the user types any rock besides granite, they will be puzzled as to why the only output is about granite. Ideally, I would like to be able to type something like:

```
print(rock.name + ' belongs to the ' + rock.group + ' group.')
```

Where no matter what the user inputs, if there's an object with a variable equal to that string, the rock variable will now be equal to said rock object. However, this doesn't work because the user is inputting a string, and not a variable class. I can get around this by adding an if statement such as:

```
if rock == 'granite':
    rock = granite
```

Though, if I do that, then I would have to write an if statement for EVERY rock object I have, and if I have A LOT of rock classes, this would be very inefficient. So my question is, is there a way to have the user input an actual variable instead of just a string? If not, any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Put all the rocks in a list or dictionary. Then use the user input to search for a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating @Barmar's suggestion. Use a dictionary:

```
rocks = {"granite": Rock('Granite', 'Igneous'), ....}
rock_name = input('Type the name of a rock: ')
rock = rocks[rock_name.lower()] # As long as it is a valid name
```

You may not even need `Rock.name` anymore.

Comment: You can store the JSON in a file, too (if your structure is a bit different)

Comment: Storing and representing are two different stories.

Comment: I mean store it like `{"granite": ['Granite', 'Igneous'], ...}` and pass it into the Rock class when loading the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the rocks in a dictionary so you can look them up by name.

```
class Rock:

    all_rocks = {}

    def __init__(self, name, group):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group
        self.all_rocks[name] = self

granite = Rock('Granite', 'Igneous')
rock_name = input("Type the name of a rock")
rock = Rock.all_rocks.get(rock_name)
print(rock.group)
```

Comment: If the dictionary is contained inside of the class, maybe also implement a `__str__` to output the correct format automatically as well.

Comment: You may even want to redefine `__dict__()`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a way to retrieve all local variables in a dict: `locals()`.

You could do sth like `rock = locals()[input("...")]`

Of course, you'd need to also handle `KeyError`s.

But since this dict contains *all* of the local variables, as soon as you have another variable which is *not* an instance of `Rock`, the user could select this irrelevant variable. You could also handle that case with `isinstance(..., Rock)`

But all of this is kind of "hacky", and using a dict with all stones mapped by name is much preferred and safe.

Answer (score 1):

There's too much input validation required for what you propose, and even after that, I don't think that's the right approach.

Continuing @DYZ's answer (he posted while I was composing), you should create a dictionary and try to match the input against the dictionary with input handling too.

```
rocksDict = {
  "rock1": Rock("Granite"),
  "rock2": Rock("Igneous"),
  "rock3": [Rock('Granite'),Rock('Granite')]
}
rockName = input('Type the name of a rock: ')

if key in rocksDict.keys(): 
    #debugging comments
    #print("Present, ", end =" ") 
    #print("value =", dict[key]) 

    type = rocksDict.get(rockName)
    print(type)
    
else: 
    print("Invalid Rock Name")
```

This way you can accommodate a multitude of rocks by just continue to filling rocksDict.

Answer (score 1):

In another twist of the idea to build an index for rocks, this solution creates a second class for the index that also indexes by group - perhaps that's your next task. A difference here is that since rocks are not indexed by a class variable, you can potentially build different rock databases. Perhaps rocks from different regions? Who knows, but since is skips a global variable at class level, it is more flexible.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Rock:
    def __init__(self, name, group):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group

class RockIndex:

    def __init__(self):
        self.by_name = {}                   # one rock by name
        self.by_group = defaultdict(list)    # many rocks by type

    def make_rock(self, name, group):
        rock = Rock(name, group)
        # normalize name a group to upper for index
        self.by_name[name.upper()] = rock
        self.by_group[group.upper()].append(rock)
        return rock


rock_db = RockIndex()
rock_db.make_rock('Granite', 'Igneous')

rock = input('Type the name of a rock: ')
try:
    grp = rock_db.by_name[rock.upper()].group
    print(f"{rock} belongs to the {grp} group.")
except KeyError:
    print("I don't know that rock")
```